# Почему после перехода на другую версию Unity при создании кнопки она не откликается на геймпад и клавиатуру?

Tags: c#, unity3d, input, button

При создании новой сцены и кнопки в ней, она не откликается на нажатие геймпада или клавиатуры, работает только при нажатии левой кнопки мыши. Те кнопки на сценах, которые были созданы на более старой версии откликаются на нажатия геймпада, клавиатуры и мыши. Я даже пробовал скопировать старые сцены, и просто отредактировать, и кнопки там продолжали откликаться на геймпад и клавиатуру. Помогите мне решить проблему. Я хочу чтобы при создании новой кнопки на новой сцене они откликались на нажатия кнопок на геймпаде или клавиатуре.
Может с переходом на другую версию это просто совпадение, но то что не откликаются кнопки на нажатия на клавиатуре или геймпаде, это факт.

Comment: Может стоит показать свой код и сказать с какой версии на какую перешел и какие ошибки выдаются в консоли? Или надо угадывать?

Comment: Я с 5.6.1f перешёл на 5.6.1f1 и появилась эта проблема. Потом перешел на 5.6.2f1 и проблема не исчезла. Код я не знаю какой должен показывать. Если вы про скрипт кнопки, то я пробовал даже поставить один и тот же скрипт с мест где он работает на новой сцене, и работала только мышь. Ошибок в консоли нет никаких.

Comment: "Сильный" переход в 5.6.1f1...Опечатался?

Comment: Сильный? Где? Я вообще не понял вас.

Comment: Комментарий свой первый прочитайте снова ('Я с 5.6.1f перешёл на 5.6.1f1 ...')

Comment: Вероятно, в старой версии компонент, обрабатывающий нажатие клавиш и кнопок цеплялся автоматически, а в этой нет? Открой сцену в блокноте, найди старую кнопку, найди новую, сравни, найди отличия.

Comment: Xumera_hZ, действительно чет тупанул, значит этот баг появился до перехода на другую версию .

Comment: @LunarWhisper я уже проверил, дело не в версии юнити. Видимо что-то случилось в настройках. Я попробовал создать новый проект, сделал две кнопки, и между ними нельзя переключаться клавиатурой, а только мышью. Как это исправить? Я вообще не понимаю! :(

Comment: Ну Edit -> Project Settings->Input - Axes проверьте, или Standalone input module. А каким образом у вас переключалось между кнопками?(и на чем сделаны эти кнопки(canvas vs collider)?)

Comment: @Xumera_hZ кнопки на Canvas. Обычный UI кнопки. Те что делал, когда первый раз ставил юнити откликаются на клаву, те что я делаю после переустановки реагируют только на мышь. Может я когда первый раз ставил что-то слуачно методом тыка правильно настроил, но сейчас я не понимаю, что делать. С настройками Input все в норме, потому что кнопки на старых сценах работают. Я даже прописал Input весь по новой, и все функционирует на сценах, где кнопки изначально адекватно работали. А где нахоидится Standalone input module я не знаю

Comment: Найди на сцене EventSystem она появляется автоматически, когда канвас создаешь, на ней должен этот модуль висеть

Comment: С ним все тоже в норме.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно назначить начальную выбранную кнопку.